# Deploying Yesod web app

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, deployment, yesod

I have a simple Yesod web app. 
I could follow the instruction in http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart, and checked `stack exec -- Yesod devel` is working fine.

The server that I use (Amazon EC2) has only one gigabyte of memory, so I can't compile the Yesod web. I used my local machine to build. Both of them use Ubuntu 14.04.

From http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp, I need three components to deploy to other machine.

1. Your executable.
2. The config folder.
3. The static folder.

I find easily the config/static folder, but I'm not exactly sure where to find the executable(s). Other than that, how to run the exeuctable without using `stack exec -- Yesod devel`?

Comment: As a side note, you can just add swap memory to use during compilation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stack build` command gives me the hints:

```
my-project-0.0.0: install
Installing library in
/home/a/my-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-3.13/7.10.2/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.2/my-project-0.0.0-Khn8lQEgR1HARzYGStlvPe
Installing executable(s) in
/home/a/my-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-3.13/7.10.2/bin
Registering my-project-0.0.0...
```

The executable is located in `/home/a/my-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-3.13/7.10.2/bin`. I could copy the files (executable, static, and config) in ~/deployment directory to check the Yesod works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the executable should be in the build subdirectory of your project directory.  I think it's a hidden directory (name starting with a dot) so you may need to run "ls -a" to see it.

To run - simply execute the executable  :)  (Append '&' to make it run in the background).

Once you have the final version you wish to go into production with, you'll probably configure the executable to start automatically when the VM boots, to detect if the executable crashed, etc.

Good luck,
Michał